# 4 variables , 3 of which have 2 groups with overlayed bar plots in RStudio - Male and Female admitted and not admitted

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lML8b.png)I am facing an issue. I want to plot all four variables in RStudio.  Where I appear to have 2 groups  for 3 variables and a Count. Yet do not have a clue how to do this with ggplot2.  On xlim axes shall be age_band and sex. On y axis Count of those admitted and not admitted.  I want the legend bellow the overlayed barplot. Can someone help? I've searched on stackoverflow and could not find a good reproducible code.

```
 dput(head(ds_sum_age_sex, 16))
 structure(list(age_band = c("0 yrs", "0 yrs", "0 yrs", "0 yrs", 
                           "1-4 yrs", "1-4 yrs", "1-4 yrs", "1-4 yrs", 
                         "10-14 yrs", "10-14 yrs", "10-14 yrs", "10-14 yrs",                              
                          "15-19 yrs", "15-19 yrs", "15-19 yrs","15-19 yrs"), 
                sex = c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
                         "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
                        "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"), 
                patient.class = c("Not Admitted", "ORDINARY ADMISSION", 
                                  "Not Admitted", "ORDINARY ADMISSION", "Not 
                                   Admitted", "ORDINARY ADMISSION", "Not 
                                   Admitted", "ORDINARY ADMISSION", 
                                   "Not Admitted", "ORDINARY ADMISSION", "Not 
                                    Admitted", "ORDINARY ADMISSION", "Not 
                                   Admitted", "ORDINARY ADMISSION", 
                                   "Not Admitted", "ORDINARY ADMISSION"), 
                Count = c(5681L, 1458L, 7667L, 2154L, 8040L, 2481L, 11737L, 
                          3601L, 2904L, 938L, 3883L, 1233L, 3251L, 1266L, 
                          2465L, 1031L)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
               "data.frame"
             ))
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck? I assume you've at least attempted some code. Questions that ask people just to complete some task for you are not well received. Instead, try to ask a clear question that someone in the future might also ask and that this post will also help them as well.

Comment: You should include your attempts and describe exactly how they fail to produce what you want. If you post an image at imgur.com and provide a link in your question, a person with higher rep can embed it in the question for you. The downvotes do not mean your question is a duplicate, it just means that users do not think the question shows research effort or is generally useful.

Comment: MrFlick, it seems that my reply  comments are deleted and not allowed on stackoverflow?

Comment: Hmm, they do seem to be gone. It's possible they may have been flagged for some reason. I don't remember what they said. I'm not able to delete comments  (other than my own) or see why there were deleted; only a site-wide moderator can do that. Questions about comments should be directed to https://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: weird enough since I have commented very much on struggles I get that may have been upsetting the site moderator. Anyway, no point to diggest on it. Surprisingly interesting. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your dput() data manually and then tried this using `facet_wrap`,

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

test_data %>%
  group_by(age_band, sex, patient.class) %>%
  summarise(total_count = sum(Count)) %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(age_band, total_count)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = patient.class), stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ sex, nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, want them overlayed, not stacked

Comment: So you want the patient.class to be one top of another (but I am unsure if that is possible since the Y axis values for them will be different)but everything else is fine? I can try, but as others have mentioned the more you provide, better is the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: I do not want then on top of each other. I want them overlayed. Meaning the not admitted to be behind the admitted. I am sorry, I am learning the language of data science as well and hard for me to reproduce all of these outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 30-second attempt:

```
library(ggplot2)
# reduce the whitespace ...
x$patient.class <- gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", x$patient.class)
ggplot(x, aes(age_band, Count, shape=sex, color=patient.class)) +
  geom_point(size=3)
```

[image: something attempted]

Comment: Sorry, missed the mention of barplot.